# Scratch memory error in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

I am a new user of photoshop. I installed photoshop in my system and now I am getting a scratch memory error in photoshop. Does anyone know how can I fix this error on my PC?

Comment: My system has a 16 GB memory https://www.allhdd.com/hpe-809081-081-memory/ Will I have to upgrade my system memory?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about software operation, not photography.

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop/using/scratch-disks-preferences.html